# Very simple dataflow beam script throws - There were errors inserting to BigQuery. Will not retry - when attempting to use WriteToBigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

A runtime error is coming up when attempting to use WriteToBigQuery in a more complicated script - it also is happening in the simplest test case possible that is included in this question. The service account has owner permissions and though the projectID datasetID and TableID are all grabbed from the pubsub message to create the dataset and table dynamically - they have all been hard coded in the WriteToBigQuery portion of the PTransform to eliminate anything odd happening dynamically. WriteToBigQuery finds the table but consistently throws this error when attempting to write anything to it - even a simple string used in the test script. Here is the error:

There were errors inserting to BigQuery. Will not retry. Errors were [{'index': 0, 'errors': [{'reason': 'invalid', 'location': '', 'debugInfo': '', 'message': ''}]}]

Many days of trying any number of tests in a more thorough script from the point where the pipeline logs the data it is about to write and everything is in order *but* then adding the WriteToBigQuery in the PTransform throws the error caused the generation of this simple example of the behavior.

The new extremely simple script was created to only create the dataset, schema, and table and then pass a single string value to print. The script successfully logs the data passed to the PTransform:

Output: {'field1': 'hello'}

And it logs it again prior to attempting the write:

Data before BQ: {'field1': 'hello'}

The logs show the content perfectly matches the schema but on attempting to write using WriteToBigQuery it throws the error:

There were errors inserting to BigQuery. Will not retry. Errors were [{'index': 0, 'errors': [{'reason': 'invalid', 'location': '', 'debugInfo': '', 'message': ''}]}]

It is also worth mentioning that without attempt to use WriteToBigQuery there are no errors at deploy or runtime. Also if the hard coded table reference is not correct it throws a different error durring runtime with information saying the it can not write to the table because it does not exist, which indicates that it gets to the point of inserting the string (in this case 'hello' and fails). One other point is that the bigquery.Client() has no problem creating the dataset, schema, or table and in a separate test the bigquery.Client() writes to the table with no problem. Because this seemed to be such a common use case and the issue was probably some carless error, many hours alone have been spent attempting to debug it prior to reaching out, but after this test generated the same error there was little else to try - so hopefully the brilliance of this group can shed some light on the issue. Please help if you can. Here is the simple test to illustrate:

```
import argparse
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam import PTransform, DoFn
from apache_beam.io import ReadFromPubSub
from apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery import WriteToBigQuery, BigQueryDisposition
from apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery_tools import RetryStrategy
import logging
import sys
import json


class ProcessVTnDFile(DoFn):
    def start_bundle(self):
        from google.cloud import bigquery
        from google.cloud import storage
        from google.api_core.exceptions import NotFound
        self.bigquery = bigquery
        self.NotFound = NotFound

    def process(self, element, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            message = json.loads(element.decode('utf-8'))
            logging.info(f"Received message: {message}")

            dataset_id = message['dataset_id']
            table_id = message['table_id']

            client = self.bigquery.Client()

            # Check if the dataset exists. Create if it doesn't.
            dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id)
            try:
                client.get_dataset(dataset_ref)
                logging.info(f"Dataset '{dataset_id}' already exists.")
            except self.NotFound:
                client.create_dataset(dataset_ref)
                logging.info(f"Dataset '{dataset_id}' created.")

            # Check if the table exists. Create if it doesn't.
            table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)
            try:
                client.get_table(table_ref)
                logging.info(f"Table '{table_id}' already exists in the dataset '{dataset_id}'.")
            except self.NotFound:
                table = self.bigquery.Table(table_ref)
                table.schema = [
                    self.bigquery.SchemaField("field1", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE")]
                client.create_table(table)
                logging.info(f"Table '{table_id}' created in the dataset '{dataset_id}'.")

            yield {'field1':'hello'}

        except KeyError as e:
            logging.error(f"Required attribute is missing in the message: {e}")



class ReadAndProcessFiles(PTransform):
    def __init__(self, topic):
        self.topic = topic

    def expand(self, pcoll):
        # Read from Pub/Sub and process files
        processed_data = (
            pcoll
            | "Read from Pub/Sub" >> ReadFromPubSub(topic=self.topic).with_output_types(bytes)
            | "Process files" >> beam.ParDo(ProcessVTnDFile())
        )

        _ = processed_data | "Print results" >> beam.Map(lambda x: logging.info(f"Output: {repr(x)}"))


        # Log data and write to BigQuery
        pipeline_result = (
            processed_data
            | "Log data before writing to BQ" >> beam.Map(lambda x: logging.info(f"Data before BQ: {repr(x)}"))
            | 'WriteToBigQuery' >> WriteToBigQuery(
                table='acep-ext-eielson-2021:2023_11_13.vtnd',
                schema='field1:STRING',
                write_disposition=BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                method=WriteToBigQuery.Method.STREAMING_INSERTS,
                insert_retry_strategy=RetryStrategy.RETRY_ON_TRANSIENT_ERROR,
                project='acep-ext-eielson-2021'
            )
        )

        return pipeline_result 
     
 

def main(argv):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--project", required=True, help="Google Cloud project ID")
    parser.add_argument("--topic", required=True, help="Pub/Sub topic")
    parser.add_argument("--runner", default="DirectRunner", help="Pipeline runner")

    args, _ = parser.parse_known_args(argv)

    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(runner=args.runner, project=args.project)
    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
        _ = pipeline | "Listen to Pub/Sub topic" >> ReadAndProcessFiles(
            topic=args.topic)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

This is the deploy.sh for the job

```
 #!/bin/bash
 
 # Ensure the script stops on first error
 set -e
 
 # Replace these values with your own settings
 export PROJECT_ID='acep-ext-eielson-2021'
 export REGION='us-west1'
 
 export STAGING_LOCATION='gs://eielson-tar-archive/staging'
 export TEMP_LOCATION='gs://eielson-tar-archive/temp'

 


 # Pub/Sub topic
 export TOPIC='projects/acep-ext-eielson-2021/topics/ps-df-bigquery-ingest'

 export SUBSCRIPTION='temp-ingest-subscription'
 
 # Install required packages
 pip install -r ./requirements.txt
 pip install -e .

# Run the Apache Beam pipeline with DataflowRunner
python src/main.py \
  --runner DataflowRunner \
  --project $PROJECT_ID \
  --topic $TOPIC \
  --subscription $SUBSCRIPTION \
  --region $REGION \
  --temp_location $TEMP_LOCATION \
  --staging_location $STAGING_LOCATION \
  --job_name ps-df-bq-vtndtest6 \
  --setup_file ./setup.py \
  --streaming
```

This is setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='gcs-file-processor',
    version='0.1',
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=[
        'apache-beam[gcp]',
        'google-cloud-bigquery',
        'google-cloud-pubsub',
        'google-cloud-storage',
    ],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataflow-cookbook/blob/main/Python/bigquery/write_bigquery_dynamic.py has the example to dynamically change the table destination based on the input data. I suggest you take a look at it.

Comment: @user2957415 were u able to figure this one out we are running the same issue here. #apache-beam #dataflow

Comment: @user2957415 I figured what the issue is, in your code you are printing the data before writing to BQ please remove 

`_ = processed_data | "Print results" >> beam.Map(lambda x: logging.info(f"Output: {repr(x)}"))`

and it should work.

Comment: If you need to print the information among the transforms, you can use `beam.transforms.util.LogElements()`